# How to keep the Date(0L) return the same result between different computer

Tags: java, date

I found out that different computer return different result from the following statement in Java.

> private static final Date ORIGIN = new Date(0L);

In my computer, it return the following result.

> Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 1969

But that's different from what it supposed to. I am thinking it should return the following result

> Thu Jan 1 16:00:00 PST 1970

How can I ensure the date is the same between different computer? What's the best practice? Thanks.

Comment: it *is* the same; Your mistake is considering a formatted date, actually being a date. What you see is the date representation under some rules (timezone specifically)

Comment: @bestsss yes, it's the same. the value is 0. the different is just the display format. but it's kind of annoying when i want to have exact the same display in two computer geographical separated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Date` is actually exactly the same. The difference is only in how it's formatted by its `toString()` method - that depends on the default `Locale` and timezone of the computer (and the timezone data in turn can depend on the Java version).

To get a consistent output, use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with a fixed pattern and a fixed timezone (in some rare cases it can still differ because of changed timezone data).

Comment: aha.. I forgot the Locale.. thanks for the SimpleDateFormat, i will check it out. thanks Michael.

Comment: I use the locale to solve my problem, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set an epoch date yourself instead of directly using 0L, you may do sth similar to below.  `This way it will return different number in different timezones`

```
    Calendar epoch = Calendar.getInstance();
    epoch.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
    epoch.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
    epoch.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 0);
    epoch.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    epoch.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    epoch.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    epoch.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    Date d = epoch.getTime();
```

However, javadoc for Date says ; "A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 `GMT`." So it is gonna do same thing when you do `new Date(0L);`

Comment: The comment is wrong, it sets the the date depending on the timezone, it'd be different. Date(0) is just perfect.

Comment: it says 1 january 1970 GMT so it specifies which timezone it takes as the reference. which part is wrong?

Comment: I refer to the code, no timezone specified [Calendar.getInstance()], so the results will differ depending on the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

And 32/64 bits has nothing to do with it either.